# How to insert images to WooCommerce Product via PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have the following code:

```
        $dproduct = new WC_Product_Simple();
        $dproduct->set_name($product['Product']['name']);
        $dproduct->set_sku($product['Product']['code']);
        $dproduct->set_price($product['Product']['sell_price']);
        $dproduct->set_regular_price($product['Product']['sell_price']);
        $dproduct->set_sale_price($product['Product']['sell_price']);
        $dproduct->set_stock_quantity($stockTotal);
        $dproduct->save();
        $image_url = wc_rest_upload_image_from_url($product['Product']['image']);
        $image_id = wc_rest_set_uploaded_image_as_attachment($upload, $dproduct->get_id());
        $dproduct->set_image_id($image_id);
        $dproduct->save();
```

But it's not updating the main image. Always shows the WooCommerce placeholder image.

What i'm doing wrong ? Thank you !

Comment: Maybe replace variable name `$image_url` with `$upload` as `$image_url` is not used and `$upload` is not defined... see it in [WooCommerce core source code](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/includes/rest-api/Utilities/ImageAttachment.php#L47). It may solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out i was using an non-existent variable

```
    $image_id = wc_rest_set_uploaded_image_as_attachment($upload, $dproduct->get_id());
```

Changed to

```
    $image_id = wc_rest_set_uploaded_image_as_attachment($image_url, $dproduct->get_id());
```

And now works